# Find a continuous subarray of size K from an array of integers, such that additional of elements from 1 to k should never go below zero

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sub-array

Given an array of unsorted integers of size n. We need to find out all continuous sub array of size k(n>k), such that in the sub array if we keep adding the elements from 1 to k, the sum should never go below zero.
For eg,
1,-3,4,-2,6,-5 (n=6, k=3)
Here the condition is passed by one subarray.(Total sum doesn't matter)
1,-3,4
-3,4,-2 
4,-2,6  Pass
-2,6,-5

Comment: So you told us your homework problem. What's the question? I mean writing a solution that works in at most about k (n - k) steps is trivial.

Comment: Not my home work, I just could not found any solution of such a problem in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Kadane's algorithm. I think you can modifie to solve your problem.